# Как получить данные переменной из фрагмента в активити?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

У меня есть activity1 в которой есть кнопка Refresh(сбрасывает данные переменной), переменная находиться в Fragment1 (допустим int i) которая инкрементируется при нажатии на кнопку, как в activity1 достать переменную (уже с данными) и сбросить ее ?

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку EventBus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фрагмент не должен ничего знать о существовании активити. Вы можете хранить эту переменную в активити и при нажатии на кнопку во фрагменте ее инкрементировать через интерфейс. А в активити ее сбрасывать имея доступ из активити.

```
public interface IOnFragmentInteractionListener {

    void onAction();
}
```

В вашем фрагменте

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private IOnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NotNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof IOnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (IOnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement IOnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    //some code

    private void yourAction(){
        mListener.onAction();
    }
}
```

И в активити реализовать интерфейс

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IOnFragmentInteractionListener {

    //some code

    @Override
    public void onAction() {
        yourVar++;
    }
}
```

Вы можете хранить вашу переменную а во фрагменте. И тогда просто при нажатии кнопки ее обнулять. Логика та же, только реализовать интерфейс должен фрагмент, а активити использовать экземпляр интерфейса.

```
public interface IFragmentController {

    void refreshVar();

}
```

В активити

```
public class Activity  {

    private IFragmentController mFragmentController;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);

        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    }

    //some code

    private void refreshVar(){
        mFragmentController = (IFragmentController) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (mFragmentController != null) {
            mFragmentController.refreshVar();
        }
    }
}
```

Во фрагменте

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment implements IFragmentController {

    @Override
    public void refreshVar() {
      // тут вы обновляете вашу переменную
    }
}
```

Comment: Если сможете напишите еще второй вариант, буду ждать, спасибо

Comment: Написал второй вариант

Comment: второй вариант отлично подошел, огромное Вам спасибо